# On the limsup of a function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $(x_n)_{ n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(y_n)_{ n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n=\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} y_n = a \in [-\infty, \infty].
$$
Does one have
$$
\limsup_{ n \rightarrow \infty} f (x_n) = \limsup_{ n \rightarrow \infty} f ( y_n) \quad?
$$
In other words, can
$$
\limsup_{ x \rightarrow a} f(x)
$$
be defined as
$$
\limsup_{ n \rightarrow \infty} f (x_n)
$$
for any $x_n \rightarrow a$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: You will need some conditions on $f$. You could define $f$ to behave differently on rationals and irrationals, and thus the limit supremum would be different to the limit itself. For a continuous $f$ it is fine.

Comment: @fGDu94 So how would limsup be defined for a general $f$?

Comment: It would defined the way it usually is

Comment: @fGDu94 there seem to be several definitions which may be equivalent. I asked you about the definition you had in mind to see whether this could lead to further discussion.

Comment: Ah ok. The definition I have in mind is: $\lim \sup_{x→a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} \sup_{y\geq x}f(y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes if $f$ is continuous. In general the answer is no: For example consider the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}1\text{ if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\-1\text{ if }x\not\in\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$. Then both the sequence  $\big\{\frac{1}{n}\big\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\big\{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\big\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to zero. But $f\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)=1\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, but $f\big(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\big)=-1\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.